# Python: Quickly loop through np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1-D np array with over 150 million data points, it is filled using np.fromfile on a binary data file.

Given that array, I need to add a value 'val' to every point unless that point equals 'x'.

Further, every value in the array, depending on its value will correspond to another value that I want to store in another list.

Explanation of variables:

** temps=np.arange(-30.00,0.01,0.01, dtype='float32')

** slr is a list, index 0 in temps corresponds to index 0 in slr and so on. Both lists are the same length

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

with open("file.dat", "rb") as f:
array = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)
f.close()

#This is the process below that I need to speed up 

T_SLR = np.array(np.zeros(len(array), dtype='Float64'))
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] != float(-9.99e+08):
        array[i] = array[i] - 273.15     
    if array[i] in temps:
        index, = np.where(temps==array[i])[0]
        T_SLR = slr[index]
    else:
        T_SLR[i] = 0.00
```

Comment: It looks as though your sensor might return only values on 0.01 degree increments.  Is that true?  And, if so, is the selection on `temps` intended to get all temperatures between -30 and 0, or do you really want just the samples that don't have a sub-hundredths fractional part going into `T_SLR`?

Comment: Yes, temps is supposed to have -30 to 0 incorporating every 0.01. Each value of temp there corresponds to a slr value found in the list slr. T_SLR is a new list (will have the same length as 'array'). The value of array is compared to temp, if it is in temp than the index is taken. That index is used to extract the value from slr. Then that is append to T_SLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowest point in your code is the O(n) traversal of list in:

```
if array[i] in temps:
    index, = np.where(temps==array[i])[0]
```

Since `temps` is not large, you can convert it to dict:

```
temps2 = dict(zip(temps, range(len(temps)))
```

And make it O(1):

```
if array[i] in temps2:
    index = temps2[array[i]]
```

You can also try to avoid `for` loop to speed up. For example, the following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] != float(-9.99e+08):
        array[i] = array[i] - 273.15
```

Can be done as:

```
array[array!=float(-9.99e+08)] -= 273.15
```

Another problem in your code is the float comparation. You shoud not use exactly equal operators `==` or `!=`, try `numpy.isclose` with a tolerance, or convert float to int by multiplying 100.

Answer (score 0):

Since your selection criteria seem to be point-by-point, there's no reason you need to read in all 150 million points at once.  You can use the `count` parameter on `np.fromfile` to limit the size of the arrays you compare at a time.  Once you process in chunks larger than a few thousand, the `for` looping won't matter and you won't exercise your memory with huge arrays derived from all 150 million points.

`slr` and `temps` looks like an indexed translation table. You could probably replace the search on `temps` with a floating comparison and a computed lookup.  Since -9.99e+8 is clearly outside the search criterion, you don't need any special treatment for those points.

```
f = open("file.dat", "rb")
N = 10000
T_SLR = np.zeros(size_of_TMPprs/4, dtype=np.float64)
t_off = 0
array = np.fromfile(f, count=N, dtype=np.float32)
while array.size > 0:
   array -= 273.15
   index = np.where((array >= -30) & (array <= 0))[0]
   T_SLR[t_off+index] = slr[np.round((array[index]+30)*100)]
   t_off += array.size
   array = np.fromfile(f, count=N, dtype=np.float32)
```

You can simplify this even more if you want `T_SLR` to contain the last entry in `slr` when the measured values is over zero.  Then, you can use

```
array = np.maximum(np.minimum(array, 0), -30)
```

to limit the range of values in `array`, and just use it for the computed index into `slr` as above (no use of `where` in this case).

Comment: I use "os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size" in the stop of size_of_TMPprs, but an getting the following error: 
                                                                   
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

with regards to T_SLR[t_off+index] = slr[int((array[index]+30)*100)]

Comment: Sorry!  int() should be np.round(), which returns an array value that can be used to index T_SLR.  I changed it in my answer.

Comment: I also noticed that there are 4 bytes in a float32, not 32, as I'd originally calculated with.  Also changed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using `with open`, don't close it yourself.  The `with` context does that automtically.  I'm also changing the generic `array` name with something that has less risk of shadowing something else (like `np.array`?)

```
with open("file.dat", "rb") as f:
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)
```

First no need to wrap `np.zeros` in `np.array`.  It already is an array.  `len(data)` is ok if `data` is 1d, but I prefer to work the `shape` tuple.

```
T_SLR = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype='Float64')
```

Boolean indexing/masking lets you act on the whole array at once:

```
mask = data != -9.99e8   # don't need `float` here
                         # using != test with floats is poor idea
data[mask] -= 273.15
```

I need to refine the `!=` test.  It is ok for integers, but not for floats.  Something like `np.abs(data+9.99e8)>1` is better

Similarly `in` is not a good test with floats.  And with integers, the `in` and `where` perform redundant work.

Assuming `temps` is 1d, the `np.where(...)` returns a 1 element tuple.  `[0]` selects that element, returning an array.  The `,` is then redundant in `index,`.   `index, = np.where()` without the `[0]` should have worked.

`T_SLR[i]` is already 0 by how the array was initialized.  No need to set it again.

```
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] in temps:
        index, = np.where(temps==array[i])[0]
        T_SLR = slr[index]
    else:
        T_SLR[i] = 0.00
```

But I think we can get rid of this iteration as well.  But I'll leave that discussion for later.

---

```
In [461]: temps=np.arange(-30.00,0.01,0.01, dtype='float32')
In [462]: temps
Out[462]: 
array([ -3.00000000e+01,  -2.99899998e+01,  -2.99799995e+01, ...,
        -1.93138123e-02,  -9.31358337e-03,   6.86645508e-04], dtype=float32)
In [463]: temps.shape
Out[463]: (3001,)
```

No wonder doing `array[i] in temps` and `np.where(temps==array[i])` is slow

We can cut out the `in` with a look at the `where`

```
In [464]: np.where(temps==12.34)
Out[464]: (array([], dtype=int32),)
In [465]: np.where(temps==temps[3])
Out[465]: (array([3], dtype=int32),)
```

If there isn't a match `where` returns an empty array.

```
In [466]: idx,=np.where(temps==temps[3])
In [467]: idx.shape
Out[467]: (1,)
In [468]: idx,=np.where(temps==123.34)
In [469]: idx.shape
Out[469]: (0,)
```

`in` can be faster than `where` if the match is early in the list, but as slow, if not more so, it the match is at then end, or there is no match.

```
In [478]: timeit np.where(temps==temps[-1])[0].shape[0]>0
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.6 µs per loop
In [479]: timeit temps[-1] in temps
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.9 µs per loop
```

---

A rounding approach:

```
In [487]: (np.round(temps,2)/.01).astype(int)
Out[487]: array([-3000, -2999, -2998, ...,    -2,    -1,     0])
```

I'd suggest tweaking:

```
T_SLR = -np.round(data, 2)/.01).astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I have incorporated your changes and appreciate the detailed response. It is however the for loop that I need to eliminate. Looping over every index of 'data' array is extremely slow and often crashes the kernal. Help with this aspect would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the shape of `temps`.  It's big.  We need to think of a better way of testing or mapping the `data` values to the 'index'.

Comment: The shape of temps (3001,0). As an FYI this is beginning to teeter on the cusp of knowledge with python. I have been able to get with my above crude methods because I have dealt with smaller files.

Comment: So I genuinely will appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Under what conditions will the numbers match or not the `temps`?  What about rounding errors?

Comment: I would simply like to round the data values to 2 decimal places, then every time a data point matches a value in temps, I take the index of where that data value lies in temps, to add the value of that same index location in slr to the new array T_SLR

Comment: I added a rounding suggestion.

Comment: So I understand the logic with the suggestions, but am struggling to implement. Do I still run the "for loop" here?

Comment: No loop - it should produce an integer array of the right size.

Comment: Okay, I am lost..
where am I finding if the value from data is in temps? the examples above are finding where a value of temps[3] exists within it self.

Answer (score 0):

Because `temps` is sorted, you can use `np.searchsorted` and avoid all explicit loops:

```
array[array != float(-9.99e+08)] -= 273.15
indices = np.searchsorted(temps, array)
# Remove indices out of bounds
mask = indices < array.shape[0]
# Remove in-bounds indices not matching exactly
mask[mask] &= temps[indices[mask]] != array[mask]
T_SLR = np.where(mask, slr[indices[mask]], 0)
```